# How to use setTimeout within a .map() in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an array of players which I map through. The user is constantly adding new players to this array. I map through the array and return a set of elements. I'd like each player from the list to render one at a time with a 500ms interval in between. Here's the code I have so far:

```
export const ShowDraftedPlayers = props => {
  const {
    draftedPlayers,
    getPlayerProfile,
    teams,
    draftPos,
    myTeam } = props;
  let playersDraftedList = draftedPlayers.map((player, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index} className='drafted'>
        <p style={style}>TEAM {player.teamDraftedBy} </p>
          <b className='player-lastName'> {player.displayName} </b>
           {player.position}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div className='draftedPlayers-container'>
      {playersDraftedList}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Basically, what would you do is keep a state of the shown drafted players, and create an interval that adds to the state array item from the props each time.

Comment: Use animate react native

Comment: You have 2 issues here,  1: setTimeout inside a map isn't really ideal, hacks like increasing the timeout values for each item is just that, a hack.  2: React doesn't work that way, you can't pausing rendering in React, like everything else that updates in React, you need to use state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an effect to create an interval which updates a counter every 500ms; your render logic can then render a growing slice of the array each time.

```
export const ShowDraftedPlayers = props => {
  const {
    draftedPlayers,
    getPlayerProfile,
    teams,
    draftPos,
    myTeam
  } = props;

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let counter = count;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (counter >= draftedPlayers.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        setCount(count => count + 1);
        counter++; // local variable that this closure will see
      }
    }, 500);
    return () => clearInterval(interval); 
  }, [draftedPlayers]);

  let playersDraftedList = draftedPlayers.slice(0, count).map((player, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index} className='drafted'>
        <p style={style}>TEAM {player.teamDraftedBy} </p>
          <b className='player-lastName'> {player.displayName} </b>
           {player.position}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div className='draftedPlayers-container'>
      {playersDraftedList}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, very helpful your function!! I have adapted to my project and I wonder if it has a way to customize the interval time instead of fixed. I have a list of array and not all items can have the same fixed amount of interval time. Thank you

Comment: @dev.doc should be possible if you call setTimeout on with a dynamic value (derived from the counter?) instead of setInterval. If you get stuck, best to ask in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. `setTimeout` is asynchronous, as so is JavaScript and React. Components are rendered as soon as possible so that JavaScript can jump to do something else. The best way is to create a hook that reacts (pun intended) to some change in value, in this case `props.draftedPlayers`, `setTimeout` for 500ms, then add that new player to an internal players state and let the component renders based on it.

Here is how the component will reflect a change in `props.draftedPlayers` with a delay of 500ms:

```
export const ShowDraftedPlayers = props => {
  const {
    draftedPlayers,
    getPlayerProfile,
    teams,
    draftPos,
    myTeam 
  } = props;

  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

  // Set internal `players` state to the updated `draftedPlayers`
  // only when `draftedPlayers` changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    const delay = setTimeout(() => {
      setPlayers(draftedPlayers);
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(delay);
  }, [draftedPlayers]);

  let playersDraftedList = players.map((player, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index} className='drafted'>
        <p style={style}>TEAM {player.teamDraftedBy} </p>
          <b className='player-lastName'> {player.displayName} </b>
           {player.position}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Whenever `draftedPlayers` prop is changed (players added or removed) from the outer context, the component will update its `players` array after a delay of `500ms`.

Comment: Consider adding `clearTimeout` so that you will only have one `setTimeout` running at once.